# Trying to delete large, redundant user file 166MB. Recycle bin hold up

Tags: windows-7

Using Win 7, 64 bit.   Recently Dell had to create a new user file for me, to solve a corruption problem.  All good, but when I try to delete the original user file (166MB) I get the error msg about the recycle bin unable to take on the delete.  Steps?  Thanks.

Comment: Try pressing shift-delete when you have the file selected. This will circumvent the recycle-bin. It may not work, but worth a try.

Comment: When you try to delete a file that's too big for the recycle bin, Windows warns you that the deletion cannot be undone. At least, that's what's *supposed* to happen. Are you sure that you got an error message and not a warning?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer and before Windows boots press <kbd>F8</kbd>, then select from advanced boot options `Safe mode`. Logon to your present account and try to delete previous one. Then restart PC again, to boot normally.

Another way is to use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), this utility tells you which program is using files you want to delete and even can delete it.